# How to remove prohibited statement from SAS log

Tags: sas

I want to make my SAS log clean, but I am getting some prohibited and restricted messages when I am creating or validating listings or tables.

It doesn't show these messages in basic validation of listings or tables, but in top level validation, they show up. If I rename some variables or if I apply a where condition, I get restricted or prohibited messages.

For example I was validating AE listings, and I had code

```
AEOUT = "fatal" then AEOUT1 = "FA";
```

At this statement, I am getting the prohibited message.

Comment: Show the message. as show your code is part of a statement, not a complete statement.

Comment: Can you clarify, what you mean by "prohibited message"?  Is this a message from SAS itself, or from your validation script? What's prohibited - the word "fatal"?